# slideToggle div by ID in Class

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to slideToggle a div which has more description when user hovers over a div with header.

HTML with Ruby:

```
<% @posts.each do |post|  %>
<%= link_to post do %>
  <div class="posts_index_div" id = <%=post.ticker%>>
     <div class="posts_index_inside_div">
       Header
     </div>
     <div class="posts_index_hover_div" id = <%=post.ticker%>>
       Description
     </div>
  </div>    
<%end%>
```

Then using jQuery first I hide all class and then I want to use slideToggle for particular div where user hovers.

```
ready = function(){
$(".posts_index_hover_div").hide();
$(".posts_index_div").hover(function(){
    $(this.id).find(".posts_index_hover_div").slideToggle();
});
};
```

You can see that, IDs are generated from model and they are equal for matching header and description, but it doesn't slide in the particular description. Help?

Comment: Instead of `$(this.id)`, just use $(this) OR try using my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.id` only returns the id name . It's not jquery object if use like prefix `"#"` so try `$("#"+this.id)` or simply use the current object `$(this)`

```
$(".posts_index_div").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".posts_index_hover_div").slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$(".posts_index_div").hover(function(){
    $("#"+this.id).find(".posts_index_hover_div").slideToggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3fND/)

Comment: .next() wont work, since the element which OP looking for is a descendant.. !

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Use this jQuery:

```
$(".posts_index_hover_div").slideToggle();
$(".posts_index_div").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".posts_index_hover_div").slideToggle();
});
```

Check out this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3fND/)..